# Button with icon and text position left

Tags: flutter

I use flutter to do `RaisedButton` with icon and the the icon and text I want change position to left. How to do it? This is my code for button.

I want do it like in the image:

[image]

```
Card(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 60,
                    child: RaisedButton.icon(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home,
                          size: 40, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      label: const Text('Electrical and Wiring',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 15)),
                      onPressed: () => {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 11):

What you can do you can use Directionality widget in flutter with `TextButton.icon()`. Here is the Code.

```
 Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: null,
              icon: Icon(
                CupertinoIcons.ellipsis_circle_fill,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              label: Text(
                "Business Name",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

And here is the View.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in the Raised Button Widget you can put a `Row()` or a `Column()` as the `child`, so it can be easily done like this,

```
RaisedButton(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.call),
        Text('Your Text'),
      ],
    ),
    onPressed: (){
    //Actions
  }),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `RaisedButton.icon()` widget..

You can get more information from [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton/RaisedButton.icon.html).

Here's a minimal example for you..

```dart
RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: null, icon: null, label: null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () {},
        child: Card(
          child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 60,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                    child: Icon(Icons.home,
                        size: 40, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                  ),
                  Text('Electrical and Wiring',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 15)),
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
```